# Looking to transform continuous variables into categorical

Tags: python, pandas

Sample Data:

```
id      val1   val2   val3  val4  val5  val6  val7
///+8yr NaN    0.0    2.0     NaN   1     3   23    
///1vjh NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   7   62
///4wu  3      NaN    6       NaN   7     8   180
```

Essentially, I want to be able to take every value that is over 5 in these row and replace them with some categorical variable (i.e. "greaterthan5"). For val7, I want to group them based on intervals of 30, for example, 0-30 gets grouped together and 31-60 will get grouped together.

I could do a for loop but I dont know if there are more efficient approaches.

Comment: Look at using `pd.cut`

Comment: I have assumed that you want a one logic for `val7` and a another logic for the other columns. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you have two questions. The first question of replacing values larger than 5 with `'larger than 5'` can be achieved with boolean indexing and the second question of grouping can be achieved with `pd.cut()`

**DEMO:**

```
d = pd.read_clipboard()
```

**Part 1**

Obtaining the values that does not satisfy the larger than 5 criteria,

```
rest = d.loc[:,'val1':'val6'][~(d.loc[:,'val1':'val6'] >5)]
rest


   val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6
0   NaN   0.0   2.0   NaN   1.0   3.0
1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   3.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Obtaining the larger than 5 values

```
larger_than_5=d.loc[:,'val1':'val6'][d.loc[:,'val1':'val6'] >5]
print(larger_than_5)

   val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6
0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   7.0
2   NaN   NaN   6.0   NaN   7.0   8.0
```

Updating with your logic,

```
larger_than_5[larger_than_5.notnull()] ='Larger than 5'
print(larger_than_5)

   val1  val2           val3  val4           val5           val6
0   NaN   NaN            NaN   NaN            NaN            NaN
1   NaN   NaN            NaN   NaN            NaN  Larger than 5
2   NaN   NaN  Larger than 5   NaN  Larger than 5  Larger than 5
```

Updating `rest` with the logic,

```
rest.update(larger_than_5)
print(rest)

   val1  val2           val3  val4           val5           val6
0   NaN   0.0              2   NaN              1              3
1   NaN   NaN            NaN   NaN            NaN  Larger than 5
2   3.0   NaN  Larger than 5   NaN  Larger than 5  Larger than 5
```

Replacing values of the original df with updated values as per logic 1

```
d.loc[:,'val1':'val6'] = rest
print(d)

        id  val1  val2           val3  val4           val5           val6  \
0  ///+8yr   NaN   0.0              2   NaN              1              3   
1  ///1vjh   NaN   NaN            NaN   NaN            NaN  Larger than 5   
2   ///4wu   3.0   NaN  Larger than 5   NaN  Larger than 5  Larger than 5   

   val7  
0    23  
1    62  
2   180
```

---

**Part 2**

Obtaining bins

```
bins = np.arange(0, d['val7'].max()+1, 30)
bins

array([  0,  30,  60,  90, 120, 150, 180], dtype=int64)
```

Creating a new series

```
val7_groups = pd.cut(d['val7'], bins)
val7_groups

0       (0, 30]
1      (60, 90]
2    (150, 180]
```

Adding that to the dataframe

```
d['val7_groups'] = val7_groups
print(d)

        id  val1  val2           val3  val4           val5           val6  \
0  ///+8yr   NaN   0.0              2   NaN              1              3   
1  ///1vjh   NaN   NaN            NaN   NaN            NaN  Larger than 5   
2   ///4wu   3.0   NaN  Larger than 5   NaN  Larger than 5  Larger than 5   

   val7 val7_groups  
0    23     (0, 30]  
1    62    (60, 90]  
2   180  (150, 180]
```

you can also set group labels by passing values to the labels parameter in `pd.cut()`