# python how to find the frequency of a range of elements in a list

Tags: python, statistics

I need to be able to find how many numbers are between a range of numbers. my ranges are `[2.5-4.5, 4.5-6.5, 6.5-8.5, 8.5-10.5, 10.5-12.5]`. then what I need is it to find the frequency of numbers in each range. so in the group of `[2.5-4.5]`, there are 6 numbers that fit in that group, `[3.01, 3.03, 3.4, 3.49, 3.5, 4.33]` all fit in that range. in `[4.5-6.5]` there are 2 that fit in that group, `[5.01, 5.13]`

```
data_points = [3.01, 3.03, 3.4, 3.49, 3.5, 4.33, 5.01, 5.13, 8.04, 10, 10, 
              10.03, 10.05, 10.12, 10.27, 10.29, 11.05, 11.38]
```

Comment: Are your ranges strings i.e. `'2.5-4.5'`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168693/looking-to-transform-continuous-variables-into-categorical

Comment: my ranges are floats

Comment: after much seaching i found this: https://dfrieds.com/data-analysis/bin-values-python-pandas.html